# Validar e capturar sequência de números

Tags: regex

Eu tenho essa sequência de caracteres:
`16-8-10-20-30-65`

Os números são aleatórios e esse é só um exemplo.

Eu preciso de uma expressão regular que valide essa sequência, capture todos os números antes do 65, incluindo os sinais de menos e excluindo o último sinal. Ou seja, no exemplo dado, isso seria `16-8-10-20-30`.

Sequências que terminem com um hífen (`16-8-`) ou tenham mais de um hífen entre dois números (`16-8--22`) não podem ser consideradas válidas. Uma sequência com um só número (`16`) pode ser considerada válida. Segue link com alguns testes: https://regex101.com/r/xF6FVQ/3/tests

O que eu consegui montar foi isso:

```
^([0-9]+-?)+[^-][0-9]*$
```

Dessa forma, a validação funciona, mas eu não consegui fazer a captura dos dados. Isso é possível?

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas é isso que está procurando? https://regex101.com/r/xF6FVQ/6

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar:

```
/([0-9\-]+)\-[0-9]+/
```

Basicamente:

- `([0-9\-]+)` cria um grupo com números e o hífen;
- `\-` casará sempre com o último hífen da expressão;
- `[0-9]+` casará sempre com o último número da expressão;

Assim, o grupo de captura irá retornar qualquer número e hífen antes do último hífen. Veja um exemplo:

```js
const pattern = /([0-9\-]+)\-[0-9]+/;

const tests = [
  "16-8-10-20-30-65",
  "9-2-4-6-8",
  "0-33-25-5667-2-9",
  "12-877-244-796",
  "12",
  "67-28",
  "1---3"
];

for (const test of tests) {
  if (test.match(pattern)) {
    let result = pattern.exec(test)[1];
    console.log(`O teste ${test} retornou: ${result}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`O teste ${test} falhou`);
  }
}
```

Perceba que, desta forma, uma expressão com múltiplos hífens seguidos também será válido.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, mas eu não tinha considerado esse cenário dos múltiplos hífens... Ele não devia passar no teste. D:

Comment: Então edite a pergunta, pois da maneira que está minha resposta resolve o problema.